# Distinguish automated vs mod vs community deletions in the 10k tools

Tags: feature-request, deleted-questions, deleted-answers, 10k-tools, vote-to-delete

I've recently been trying to make the Recently Deleted section of the 10k tools a semi-regular port of call for auditing site moderation, and I find it to be rather less useful than it could be.

At present, it just offers an unstructured list:

> [image]

However, there's several channels that end up here, and they have different auditing requirements, so here's a request:

- Please add a middle column indicated whether the deletion was enacted by the OP, by a moderator, via a review queue (ideally with a link to the review), by community members directly on the post, or via automated deletion by the Community bot (in which case marking out, via an acronym or something, the RemoveAbandonedClosed / etc. channel in use).

This doesn't sound like a huge performance load or a huge chunk of code (but then again, don't they always) and it would make the list much easier to parse, particularly when it has long stretches of automated deletions mixed in with manual deletions that require more attention.

Comment: What do we mean by "auditing site moderation" here, exactly? Asking as a mod (though not on this site, whatever it is)

Comment: Just having a look at what got deleted and making sure that nothing got trampled that shouldn't have, particularly via community and queue deletions. *Not* the formal auditing mechanism as in bigger sites.

Comment: The current design is made even more frustrating by the fact that every time you go to that page, including if you click through to something and then come back, the list is collapsed so you only see three items.  So you keep having to expand the list and find where you were again.

Comment: @MonicaCellio That's OK, though ─ it's not like it's a list that's meant to be used in a "here's a bunch of items that need a brief look, and then you come back here for the next item" kinda way.

Comment: I'm not following.  Right now I *have* to click through to see what happened, even what kind of deletion it was.  Then I come back and, blam, my expanded list is gone again.  (How do *you* use that list?)  Your proposal gives me useful information before clicking, which will reduce that pain.

Comment: @MonicaCellio That last comment may or may not have been as full of sarcasm as I could make it ;-). (That said, I normally open a bunch of new tabs in batches, but I think your usage is perfectly reasonable and your frustration is perfectly legitimate.)

Comment: Oh, a failed Detect Sarcasm roll -- got it. Yeah, I'd rather not have to spawn tabs for every "quick look" that I want to take; I spawn tabs when I'm going to need to do something more substantial but don't want to do it right this instant.