# Make chat just a lil' bit more visible?

Tags: feature-request

Right now if I want to go to chat on another community, I have to go to that community via the menu, then reopen the menu and select chat.

Why can we not just have the chat link visible for each community? I know some people will say 'well chat is dead for community X' - it'll never be alive if people don't even know it's there...

[image: Chat links for everyone!]

Comment: The Chat link can be found in the footer as well, except on Stack Overflow. Please don't clutter that top bar with more links. Maybe, just maybe it could go in the leftbar if that rolls out to all sites but chat really isn't that important or helpful to get better content on the sites.

Comment: I don't see it as clutter, it's taking up wasted space...

Comment: Also I'm trying to imagine how well smokey would work without chat....

Comment: For 99.99% of the users, it will just be total noise since they don't use chat at all. Even for me it would be noise since I'm active in chat only in two sites, I don't need that link on other sites, and it's just distracting.

Comment: Blasphemy! The top bar is a sacred ch-ch-ch-changes. How dare you suggest "improvements" to it? Stack Exchange has already perfected it and won't take any feedback.

Comment: @Shadow I am willing to bet more people would find the chat link useful than the garbage called company blog, so why not get rid of that clutter first? Also, if you don't use those links, you can simply turn them off. We can even make that the default option. Don't get in the way of those who want to just because you don't want to.. How frequently do users click on 'edit' in that menu, by the way?

Comment: @ShadowWizard you get distracted by _links_ ? Using google must be really hard for you.

Comment: @djsmiley2k by anything that is as wide as the reputation, is fixed width, etc. If it will appear only on hover that would be fine though.

Answer (score 5):

#### Why can we not just have the chat link visible for each community?

This functionality is provided by the [SOX](https://github.com/soscripted/sox) add-on:

> The SOX userscript adds a bunch of optional features to all sites in the Stack Exchange network. These can be toggled on or off from an easy to use control panel

One of the features is:

[image]

Here it is in action:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

In early iterations of SE - until [about 4 years ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207420/the-new-top-bar-is-out-on-meta-consider-it-a-beta), chat was actually on the top bar, and I personally wouldn't be on chat if it was hidden away as it is now (cue shocked gasps). I actually feel that chat's less used than it is cause it's so darned hard to find. The most recent chatrooms I've joined (Cooking's main room and Pets' main room), is due to me wanting to check scope for the former, and a mod inviting me for the latter. I wouldn't have come across it as I did, say Root Access (Super User's main chatroom).

The reasoning for pulling chat off the top bar is that

> The thought process behind moving these links is that the "site switcher" should be an automatic place to go when you are on a site and want to go to another one. If you haven't already developed the muscle memory for these links, getting between them required a bit of a cognitive load: You must first decide that you want to switch sites and then you have to decide which area to go to to switch.

and

> It is true that we have added a click in the process, but we have also removed a lot of clicks for other common actions that are much more frequent than switching between main and meta.

*Personally* I think the end result of sticking it in the site switcher is that we've basically de-emphasised "integral" parts of the site that aren't part of the core QA experience. It's not really as obvious, and over time we've erred towards simplifying that top bar as much as possible, and 'deepening' how far someone needs to go outside Q&A so that less of the seemingly 'extra' features are obvious.

(Arguably, Careers isn't a core QA feature but it makes SE money....)

I've actually recently argued that chat and meta belong on [the new left bar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/307886/135565) - which unifies the features of the site in one place. Considering the trajectory SE is taking, I think the process of streamlining the top bar isn't bad, but if I can't see something when I'm looking at a page, I'm unlikely to find something I don't already know about. So yeah, I'm for better visibility *but* I don't think the top bar's the place for it.