# Options in hamburger menu moved down

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, top-bar

I noticed that the options present in hamburger icon i.e., help, chat and log out are misaligned. This is how it looks. They moved to next line.

[image: Top bar on movies &TV with options changing place]

It is the same in Hinduism, Vegetarianism, Science Fiction and some more sites along with metas. But this remains as earlier like that is on Meta Stack Exchange.

[image: Hamburger menu on meta stack exchange]

Is this a new change or a bug by any chance? Almost every site I have checked it is not like the Meta Stack Exchange. The options have moved down.

Comment: Yeah, that's new (and a bug). Will fix.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Fixed in the next build, thanks. I had to update the top bar dialog layout to support non-fixed widths (in preparation for [responsiveness](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307862/ch-ch-ch-changes-left-nav-responsive-design-themes)), and forgot to add a CSS class to some elements.

Comment: The icons/text areas in the inbox are doing weird things now (not in FF, though)...

Comment: @Catija If you're talking about [narrow, cut-off site icons](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/6857289#6857289), I'm fixing that right now. If there's something else, can you be more specific?

Comment: Ah! Yes, that's it! I wasn't sure if it was the text padding obscuring the icons or if the icons weren't rendering properly. :)

Comment: @Catija Cool, thanks. Fix for that is in the next build.