# Menu UI in chat broken

Tags: bug, design, chat, top-bar

The menu drop down for rep,messages as well as main StackExchange menu  in [Stackoverflow Chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com), [Stackexchange Chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com) as well as [Meta Stackexchange chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com) are broken.

Below images are from StackOverflow chat but could see the same in both other links.

## Reputation

[image]

There seems to be no padding and it looks like its squished.

## Messages

[image]

The chat reply/comment seems to have gone down and the icon seems to be touching the top. Not the case in the main sites.

## Site toggle menu

[image]

This looks like a remnant of [Options in hamburger menu moved down](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/309022/options-in-hamburger-menu-moved-down) bug report in addition to no padding in site options.

This is in latest stable Chrome in Mac OS Sierra