# Options in hamburger moved down in Area 51

Tags: bug, design, area-51, top-bar

This is same bug as [Options in hamburger menu moved down](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/309022/357396) which is [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed). This got reproduced. It is on Area51 this time.

[image: Image of hamburger menu on Area 51]

help, chat and logout should be in the first line but they moved down. The padding in the communities list is also affected.

[image: Image of Hamburger menu from Meta.SE]

This is how it should be.

I believe that the reason is same as the previous bug report i.e., experiments on layout for [responsive design](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/307862/357396).