# Right margin, that's not right

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, mobile-web

There's some margin to the right of the menu which wasn't there before some time today. I believe is not right. Something must have gone wrong.

#### Current

[image]

#### Previous

[image]

Chrome 66 from Play Store

Comment: I don't see anything that looks wrong. Would you care to elaborate on your perceptions?

Comment: @JeffZ The menu used to occupy the whole page without leaving any margin.

Comment: Not that I ever recall seeing in the over-a-year that I've been a StackExchange member...

Comment: The same issue is in the site-switcher too.

Comment: The "margin" is the space reserved for achivements. If it was different before (I don't remember), the current design is better, I vote to keep it this way. (i.e. not fix this "bug")

Comment: @Arulkumar And it looks even worse there.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I added another screenshot from times ago.

Comment: This is even more annoying if you're a moderator and have an extra icon at the right, because the margin becomes even larger... (and doesn't even line up with the inbox icon anymore).

Comment: @animuson Thanks for your response! Does that imply that you agree it's a bug?

Comment: Well, still prefer this "new" style, but agree it might be a bug.

Comment: Can you take a screenshot when you have changes in rep? The green notification goes out of the right margin to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed in the next build, thanks. This came from a change I made for medium widths in the work-in-progress [responsive mode](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307862/ch-ch-ch-changes-left-nav-responsive-design-themes) to ensure that top bar dialogs never extend outside the left edge of the window, but that wasn't handling the exisiting mobile skin correctly.