# Make the site menu buttons adapt properly to half-screen size of FullHD resolution

Tags: feature-request, design

Often enough I find myself snapping Stack Overflow or another SE site window to the left/right side of the 1920x1080 screen and have Visual Studio or SSMS on the other half, and the site doesn't look right at this width. Even though it's a pretty expected thing, in my opinion. FullHD resolution is pretty popular. It seems like the smallest width a page can be without starting to look weird is 1090 pixels. But in my case (Windows 7, so window borders and scrollbar are different from Windows 10) it's 925 pixels.

I remember there was a poll or a silent stats survey which has shown what the smallest resolution is, but I guess this use case wasn't taken into account.

The site's top menu buttons are clipped by the window size and there's a weird distance from the right side, approximately as wide as the scrollbar.

[image]  >> [image]

I'm not asking to do anything about side widgets on the right, just the main menu strip buttons so that the "Ask question" button fits inside the window. Thanks.

Comment: [Responsive design is coming soon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/307862/307988)

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveHedgehog with 5k rep I think you should know that marking questions as duplicates is for when they are the exact same. I don't think a meta announcement of changes is the same as a design bug/request. The link to that post has already been added in the comment above, and the relationship has been established, but the answer to my "question" (actually bug report / feature request) is not found among any "answers" (it's not a question) to that "question" (it's an announcement).

Comment: Here on Meta Stack Exchange, the guidelines for closing questions as duplicates are much broader, and it's not uncommon for a question to be closed as a duplicate even though they're only closely related. That post is an official announcement of the adoption of responsive design, which is what you asked for in your post. For more information, see the last section of our [FAQ on closing as duplicates](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10844/377214).