# Is it possible to remove left section on the Stack Exchange sites

Tags: support, sidebar

I realize I never used the left hand side of the any Stack Exchange site that contains: `Home`, `Find a job`, `Teams`. I have a small screen, where terminal and the web-browser is open side to side. So hiding this section might help to save same space for me.

[image]

*[Q]* Is it possible to hide/remove section inside the red rectangle to increase the width for the text that contains the answers. Basically when I am reading answers I just want a focus to the middle sections and ignore the tags on left and right hand side in order to improve productivity.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I remove or hide the left navigation bar?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/311236/how-can-i-remove-or-hide-the-left-navigation-bar)

Comment: The right sidebar can be hidden with a user-script or user-style.

Comment: The left sidebar ([tag:left-nav]) has been announced here: [Left nav, responsive design, and theming next steps](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/309349/289905). [Related](https://google.com/search?q=site%3Ameta.stackexchange.com+hide+sidebar): [Collapse right sidebar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/318430/289905), [How to avoid “Hot Network Questions” on the sidebar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/222721/289905).

Comment: @ user289905 thanks, is there any example script to hide right sidebar removing everthing except `Linked` and `Hot Network Questions` section

Comment: See Stack Apps, e.g. [Hide the Community Bulletin](https://stackapps.com/q/4844).