# Allow users to use responsive theme on all sites while logged in on a mobile browser

Tags: feature-request, mobile-web, responsive-design

I (like many SE users) prefer the new responsive theme offered by SE as it has far more functionality and is simply more appropriate for my needs.

However I must manually scroll to the bottom of each site's home page and then use the full site button to toggle the responsive theme for multiple sites.

**My feature request is**: Can a setting be implemented that lets users force responsive theme use on all sites while logged in?

Comment: Are you saying that you've previously disabled responsiveness everywhere and now you want to be able to undo that across the board, or are you saying that things are coming up as non-responsive even though you've never set that?  (I ask because for me, all sites are responsive by default.)

Comment: I say that sometimes sites are not responsive for me while logged in so I want a toggle to force it at server level.

Answer (score 2):

I use Stack Exchange on my phone a lot... and not just because it's my job. For the last couple of years I've switched between the iOS app, mobile site, and full site whenever I was using the site while mobile, particularly for moderation purposes as the app doesn't allow much in the way of moderation.

OK, to be honest, I didn't ever use the mobile skin much, instead zooming and scrolling around on the full site on my tiny screen, complaining every time a link was too small for my fingers to tap easily. Despite that, I still would have used this even before the responsive design. The mobile skin just doesn't do much for me that I couldn't already do in the app.

Now that we have a much more responsive site, it makes sense to allow users who prefer the new responsive view to set that as a network-wide setting rather than making them scroll to the bottom of the page every time they visit a site in a mobile browser.

---

#### What does it look like now?

Mobile users are shown the mobile skin by default. They can switch to the full site view by scrolling to the bottom of the page and clicking the "full site" button in the footer. Depending on the page they're on, this may take a lot of scrolling.

After clicking on "full site", that choice is retained for that site alone through a cookie. Subsequent visits to that site will default to full site view until the cookie expires.

This process must be repeated for each site as there is no way to choose a default setting.

#### What could it look like?

Registered users could have a preference on their site settings page that allowed them to indicate either the mobile skin or full site view as their default mobile view. Any time they visited a Stack Exchange site, they'd be shown it in that default view, across the network, as long as they are logged in.

The mobile/full site link would still exist in the footer, allowing users to switch which view they're currently using and still setting a cookie when that site's preferred view was different than their default choice, overriding it for that site alone. This allows users to view selected sites in the view opposite their default setting if they choose. It also retains the on-page access to switch views on demand.

I'd really love having this as a user setting.

---

#### But, wait... is the mobile skin even going to be around much longer?

All this assumes that the mobile skin will be sticking around for a while. One of the initial plans for responsive design was to retire it once the entire site was responsive. From [Ch-ch-ch-changes: Left nav, responsive design, & themes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307862/ch-ch-ch-changes-left-nav-responsive-design-themes) :

> Once all our pages are responsive we plan on doing some additional work to make sure everything works great on phones. At that point we will retire the mobile skin.

There's little reason for us to spend time creating this setting if the mobile skin is going away soon. At this point, we still have many pages that need to be made responsive including user profiles, the review queues, and all of the pages associated with moderation. On top of this, we've got some work to do to ensure the pages are optimized for small devices.

I don't get to make these decisions - really, that's for the best - but depending on the planned timeline for full responsiveness, maybe we can find a solution to this.

Comment: I've tried to use responsive pages on my phone with the responsive design, and even those ones have a ways to go yet.  I hope they won't take away the mobile view until all pages (a) are responsive and (b) actually work well on a phone.

Comment: That is what the quote from Joe's post says. :) I don't think there's any plans to get rid of the mobile site soon. I just have no clue how long finishing the responsive pages and optimizing for mobile will take.

Comment: One thing to consider with this setting: phones and tablets bot get served the mobile site by default; on my phone that's what I want (until the responsive design works), while on my 10" tablet I want the responsive site.  I don't think this is an uncommon use case, so please think about how a global preference would interact with that.

Comment: I don't actually know if there's a way to address that but if there's not, having the ability to choose which is the default doesn't really change anything. If you use your tablet more often, you default to full site and switch to mobile view on your phone once per site to set the cookies there... if you do the opposite, you leave it the way it is. It doesn't make it more complicated than it already is, it just allows users who want the same view on every site on every device able to do that with a single flip of a switch.

Comment: Yeah, I guess that makes sense since it's a settable default (and not a system-imposed one).  I was having visions of having to go through and individually set them all *again*, but with the right setting there shouldn't be a disruption.